# Dynamic counter that changes without page reload

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, jquery

I have a website running php with a mySQL database. For every visitor I have coming to the site I log the user sessions (from the past 5 minutes) in a separate table.

How can I make a dynamic counter on the page that would change the amount of active sessions without reloading the page, i.e. if I am on the website and 15 other people come in the counter would automatically change without me reloading the page.

Answer (score 1):

In the very basic case you could poll a server script via AJAX. That PHP script would respond with some desired information like online user number, those user names, etc. So example javascript part:

```
// Poll the server each 60 seconds
window.setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('/online_users.php', function(data) {
        // Here the data JSON returned by a PHP script
        // e.g. data.count - count of sessions online
        // data.users - could be array of user objects, etc
        $('#counter').text(data.count); // Update some DOM element with new number
    });
}, 60000);
```

And the server side `online_users.php`:

```
<?php

// connect to DB, perform all necessary operations
// output needed info in JSON format

$users = array(
    array('username' => 'Tomas', 'id' => 234),
    array('username' => 'Jassy', 'id' => 42)
);
$count = count($users);

header('Content-type: application/json');
die(json_encode(array(
    'count' => $count,
    'users' => $users
)));
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried this with the code you provided but nothing is being output. I have to look into it a bit closer. just one question.. I don't need to 'echo' the count for it to be able to show? thanks

Comment: The code I've provided works just fine. Just look closer. And yes of course you need your php script to output something back as a responce. `echo`, `die`, `print`, etc. If you need just a number you can simply change to `echo 25;` or `die(25)`.

Comment: You can also change the interval to be less then 1 minute, maybe that's why you there was no output, because 1 minute has to pass first.